# What does a dot (.) means after a numeric value in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

This is my first time using an ORACLE SQL.
I came across with a query like this :

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE_A
WHERE COLUMN_A = 1.
AND COLUMN_B <> 0.
```

Can anyone explain me what does a dot (.) after those integers means? Will it make any difference if I don't put a dot (.)?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: In most languages the `.` after a number will force the compiler/interpreter to treat this number as a floating point number instead for an _integer_. If it will make a difference depends on the taken operation and on what kind of datatype the compiler/interpreter expects for the operation.

Comment: As @t.niese says, in most programming languages there is a difference between INTEGER (of different kinds and precisions) and FLOAT/DOUBLE etc. In such language, 5/2 = 2 but 5./2 = 5.0/2 = 5/2. = 2.5.  Unfortunately, even though most of Oracle is written in C, and C makes the distinction between INTEGER and FLOAT (integer arithmetic is much faster, and in some cases it is what's needed), Oracle does NOT make that distinction. Missed opportunity on their part. So, in Oracle, there is absolutely no difference between 1,  1.    and 1.0

Answer (score 1):

It will just add `0` after the decimal point. It has no effect. It is equivalent to

```
1. = 1.0
0. = 0.0
```

If the datatype `COLUMN_A` is `decimal` then based on scale of `COLUMN_A` number of zero's after the decimal point will vary.

Answer (score 0):

I've never seen numbers represented without the decimal 0 (zero) afterward, but it looks like that's what's happening here.

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE_A
WHERE COLUMN_A = 1.0
AND COLUMN_B <> 0.0
```

which is the same as

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE_A
WHERE COLUMN_A = 1
AND COLUMN_B <> 0
```

Comment: I have seen numbers like 1. in the US (I grew up in Eastern Europe and I hadn't seen it before either).